# cython module raises ImportError even though I'm linking in the necessary static libs

Tags: python, static-libraries, cython, distutils, undefined-reference

My cython module builds fine, but when I try to import it I get the following error:

```
ImportError: ./pyflite.so: undefined symbol: basic_ff_register
```

here's my setup.py.

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

ext_modules = [Extension("pyflite",
                         ["pyflite.pyx"],
                         extra_objects=[
                                   "/usr/local/lib/libflite.a",
                                   "/usr/local/lib/libflite_cmulex.a",
                                   "/usr/local/lib/libflite_usenglish.a",
                                   "/usr/local/lib/libflite_cmu_us_slt.a"])]

setup(
  name = 'pyflite',
  cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
  ext_modules = ext_modules
)
```

as you can see, since the libs are static, I had to add them to `extra_objects` rather than `libraries`

Here's what's puzzling me:

```
nm -o --defined-only /usr/local/lib/*.a | grep 'basic_ff_register'

/usr/local/lib/libflite.a:cst_ffeatures.o:00000000000017a0 T basic_ff_register
```

doesn't that mean that that the function is in `libflite.a` which I'm linking with?

Any help would be appreciated,

-Scott

Answer (score 0):

Try to reverse the order in which you link the static libraries. libflite.a (where the symbol is missing) should not be first.